# How to get monthly average active orders

Tags: mysql

I have orders table which has the start date, end date and anticipated end date columns, I can able to get all the active work orders in month but I am looking for selected month average working orders.

I am trying to find an idea to get but unable to get, can someone please help on this?

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/353f1/1)

Updated [Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/353f1/16) (Can we combine those 3 queries into single Query1+Query2-Query3 = desired count which is 7 in this case)

Updated as per the comments:
Average working means for example there are thousands of orders are in the database and some might close in the middle of the month and some might start in the start of the month some might start in the next month. So I want to know on average how many orders are working in the month.

Desired Result or Count is: 7, because 4 Orders are closed in the month and 4 are started in the month.

**MySQL 5.6 Schema Setup**:

```
 CREATE TABLE `orders` (
    `id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `order_num` BIGINT(20) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `start_date` DATE NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `anticpated_end_date` DATE NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `end_date` DATE NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
)
COLLATE='utf8_general_ci'
ENGINE=InnoDB
AUTO_INCREMENT=1
;
    INSERT INTO `orders` (`order_num`, `start_date`, `anticpated_end_date`, `end_date`) VALUES
  ('124267', '2019-01-11', '2020-01-10', '2020-01-10'),
  ('464335', '2019-01-03', '2019-11-15', '2019-12-13'),
  ('313222', '2019-01-03', '2020-02-15', NULL),
  ('63356', '2019-04-12', '2019-05-15', '2019-06-13'),
  ('235233', '2020-01-20', '2020-11-15', NULL),
  ('313267', '2019-01-03', '2020-01-15', '2020-01-19'),
  ('123267', '2019-12-10', '2020-07-31', NULL),
  ('234523', '2019-12-07', '2020-10-15', NULL),
  ('12344', '2020-01-03', '2020-02-15', NULL),
  ('233523', '2019-01-03', '2020-01-02', '2020-01-02'),
  ('233423', '2020-01-05', '2020-03-15', NULL),
  ('45644', '2020-01-11', '2020-08-15', NULL),
  ('233723', '2019-06-03', '2020-01-05', '2020-01-05'),
  ('345234', '2020-02-02', '2020-02-15', NULL),
  ('232423', '2020-02-03', '2020-03-15', NULL);
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT order_num, start_date, anticpated_end_date, end_date
FROM orders
WHERE start_date <= date("2020-01-31")
AND
 (
         (
                 end_date IS NULL AND
                         (
                                 anticpated_end_date >= date("2020-01-31") OR
                                 anticpated_end_date BETWEEN date("2020-01-01") AND date("2020-01-31")
                         )
         ) OR
         (
                 end_date >= date("2020-01-31") OR
                 end_date BETWEEN date("2020-01-01") AND date("2020-01-31")
         )
    );
```

Comment: Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/60002206/edit) your question to provide sample data and expected results so others can better undertand what you are looking for. Also, you might need to provide more than 2 records so your dataset is representative of your use case.

Comment: Is a working order one which ends or is anticipated to end in a given month?

Comment: @GMB Thanks will update shortly

Comment: @Nick end date is null then it is working order

Comment: *"I am looking for selected month average working orders"* Would you please clarify this ?

Comment: @Strawberry give me some more time I am working on adding more records

Comment: @vvr02, what *month average working orders* means?

Comment: @Cid average working means for example there are 100's of orders are in the database and some might close in the middle of the month and some might start in the start of the month some might start in the next month. So I want to know on average how many orders are working in the month.

Comment: What is the desired result? Edit your question accordingly.

Comment: @Strawberry updated as per the suggestion

Comment: @Strawberry I have updated fiddle is there anyway that we can combine them to write a single one http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/353f1/16

Comment: A couple of observations that may or may not be pertinent: 1. date() is redundant in this context, and just adds to the confusion. Get rid of it. 2. Events typically have a start and end. An Event overlaps a date range if the Event starts before the range ends and ends after the range starts.

Answer (score 0):

For the first query, I find this easier to read...

```
SELECT order_num, start_date, anticpated_end_date, end_date 
  FROM orders 
 WHERE start_date < '2020-01-01'
   AND COALESCE(end_date,anticpated_end_date) > '2020-01-31';
```

If you're only interested in the count of that result, then consider the following...

```
SELECT SUM(start_date < '2020-01-01' AND COALESCE(end_date,anticpated_end_date) > '2020-01-31')n 
  FROM orders;
```

Does that help?

Comment: Are you suggesting similar to this http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/353f1/26 ?

Comment: @wr02 Not that, but similar to that - and without all those pointless `dates()`

Comment: Ok I will cross check it anyway thanks for the help

Comment: Also, what's the difference between `anticpated_end_date >= '2020-01-01'` and `anticpated_end_date >=  "2020-01-31" OR anticpated_end_date BETWEEN "2020-01-01" AND "2020-01-31"`?

Comment: They both are same, initially I was written it for different reason eventually changed it, I overlooked afterwards

Comment: Regarding the dates as far as I remember reading a article which suggest that with using dates() results might not be accurate, was it not right?

Comment: In the context of a date data type, the date() function is redundant, and (in some cases, though not this one) even counterproductive - because functions cannot use indexes.

Comment: This is what I was thinking final query any improvements http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/353f1/36 This is the first time I am using COALESCE this function

Comment: Looks good. I would give the result an alias, and I would experiment with constructing an index on some combination of start_date and the remaining date columns.

Answer (score -1):

I am assuming that if the end date is marked as null then it is an active order else the order is not active.
So all active orders for month of Jan would be where end date is null and the start date is on or before 31 Jan 2020.
Based o above 2 assumptions the resulting query would look like this:

**select order_num, start_date, end_date, anticpated_end_date
from orders
where end_date is null
and start_date <= date("2020-01-31")
order by start_date,end_date,anticpated_end_date;**